# Can't import module in folders aside from home

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, module, pip

I was trying to install the module, tweepy, through the python3 shell on Ubuntu in a folder called dtrump in my home directory (donald trump response twitter bot), except it keeps saying "ImportError: No module named 'tweepy'". While you may think I simply did not install tweepy, I have, I even uninstalled to reinstall. The weird thing is I can import tweepy through the shell as long as I'm in the home directory and no child folders. I am running the latest version of python, pip, and ubuntu.

Comment: Did you install with `pip3` if you're using `python3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

This should help